# Navigate from facebook tab to canvas page

Tags: facebook, facebooker

My facebook application has a tab the user can install. On this tab, there is links that are suppose to link to application canvas (ex.: apps.facebook.com/my-app).

It seems that when I'm on my user profile tab and click on a link, Facebook loads the page inside the tab. How do I force it to navigate out of the tab and into the canvas page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use full urls instead of relative urls.

For example:

```
<a href="/apppage/content.php">Link</a> -> Renders on tab
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp/apppage/content.php">Link</a> -> Renders application page
```

Good luck!

Comment: You are completely right! I always use `_path` instead of `_url` in rails and just assumed Facebooker was fixing the URLs. Good to know! Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the regular rails `link_to` function and pass `:only_path => false`. This will include the host name into your URL which will be your app's canvas page. When you click it within a Facebook tab, you will go to the app's canvas page instead of staying in the tab.

```
<%= link_to "Leave the tab", :controller => 'home', :only_path => false %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parent attribute in anchor tag.

For example:

```
<a href="http://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE" target="_parent">Click Me</a>
```

This will solve it.